# Dominio con o sin www y consecuencias de cambio

Tags: seo, dominio

tengo sitio web con el dominio con www por defecto desde hace tiempo, con redirecciones 301 desde la versión sin www.
Estoy añadiendo / modificando directivas de seguridad del `.htaccess` y haciendo una comprobación de [*elegibilidad HSTS*](https://hstspreload.org/) obtengo el siguiente error:

> **Error: Subdomain**
>
> `www.midominio.es` is a subdomain. Please preload `midominio.es` instead. (Due to the size of the preload list and the behaviour of cookies across subdomains, we only accept automated preload list submissions of whole registered domains.)

Si lo entiendo correctamente *debo seleccionar el dominio sin **www** como predeterminado*.
Tendría que hacer cambios en el sitio, en *google search console*, etc. pero **¿qué consecuencias negativas puede tener este cambio en un sitio web que lleva tiempo funcionando (SEO, etc)?**

Answer (score 0):

Ninguna, google lee los dominios por la url no por la ip del servidor, al cambiar y quitar el www solo se cambia en el dns pero el contenido y los links del sitio siguen siendo los mismos por lo que no tendria que afectar en lo mas minimo a no ser que migres tu sitio a otro dominio [Referencia](https://boluda.com/tutorial/quitar-las-www-de-tu-web-en-wordpress/)

Comment: https://boluda.com/tutorial/quitar-las-www-de-tu-web-en-wordpress/

Comment: Me parece que mezclas conceptos. Aquí no tienen nada que ver la IP del servidor o las DNS. En cuanto a que "google lee los dominios por la url", sería lo mismo usar `https://midominio.es` que `https://www.midominio.es`. Si se hace al inicio, como bien dice la página que refieres que es una *guía de inicio*. Si usas ambos dominios, estas duplicando contenido y Google te puede penalizar, de hay que se elige uno y se redirecciona (301) el otro, de otro modo puedes abrir tus páginas con ambas opciones, y aunque tu tienes 1 página, Google lee 1, con el mismo contenido.

Comment: Cuando cambias entre `https://midominio.es` y `https://www.midominio.es` o viceversa un sitio después de estar online durante algún tiempo, es cuando viene el problema, quiero saber ¿qué implica? Si haces bien la migración todo funciona, pero para Google un sitio que tenía indexado desaparece y aparece otro nuevo con su mismo contenido... ¿qué supone esto a efectos de SEO? ¿Pierdes el *Google juice* o se va a mover? ¿posibles penalizaciones?

Comment: Para el crawler de google tu sitio seria el mismo, solo que sin redireccion www es como que ya no sepas cual es tu casa solo por pintar la fachada, google usa el site map, el dominio y el código, podrias cambiar de dominio pero mientras mantengas tu sitio optimizado al algoridmo de google y con buenas practicas de programacion puedes incluso superar el posisionamiento de tu antiguo dominio [https://borjaarandavaquero.com/algoritmo-de-google/]